# Restkit, put parameters in path

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit, restkit-0.20

I want to consume this api endpoint

```
.../country/search/{query}
```

another way would be

```
.../country/search?query={query}
```

however the api does not support that. How can I support the first style with restkit and not violate the path pattern?

```
pathPattern:@"/country/search/"
```

is not recognized by

```
getObjectsAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"country/search/%@", query]
```

so restkit fails to load the correct mapping.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set your path pattern to:

```
pathPattern:@"country/search/:query"
```

See [sockit](https://github.com/NimbusKit/sockit) for a description of hoe the path pattern matching works.

Also, ensure that your leading slashes match.